# Having trouble implementing Code Prettify in Jekyll—want to use `` instead of <pre></pre>

Tags: html, css, jekyll, google-code-prettify

I've been trying to implement *[Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)* in my Jekyll [blog](https://github.com/pdelfan/blog). I followed some guides and was able to implement it, but it's not ideal. This is what I did:

**1-** I went to `_includes` and added the necessary files in `head.html`:

The sunburst theme:

`<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?autoload=true&amp;skin=sunburst&amp;lang=css" defer="defer"></script>`

The CSS file of the theme (it is in my `css` folder on GitHub):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/prettify.css" rel= 'stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

**2-** For example, I used the tag `<pre class= "prettyprint"></pre>` to test it. As you can see in this [post](http://pdelfan.me/blog/jekyll/update/2016/02/22/on-life.html) (the code block is at the bottom of the page), it does work. If you notice, you see that `<iostream>` is missing because I used `<pre></pre>` and therefore it sees the `<>` characters, takes them as HTML and doesn't show `<iostream>`. This is how it looks:

[image]

I could use HTML entities to fix it, but this is not ideal. I've searched for 2 hours and couldn't find a reliable source to fix this.

---

So my **question** is:

Is it possible to make *Code Prettify* work in markdown, using `` instead of `<pre></pre>`? If not, is there another way to implement it in Jekyll? Or make it easier to use? If none of these are possible, is there a better alternative to Jekyll which supports `Code Prettify`?

If you need to see other files please do check my [repository](https://github.com/pdelfan/blog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jekyll, you can use two highligting methods :

#### backtick-style fenced-code

In `_config.yml`, set :

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

Highlight your code like this :

````
``` c
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
cout << "and then there were none" << endl;
return 0;
}
```
````

### With highlight liquid tag

```
{% highlight c %}
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
cout << "and then there were none" << endl;
return 0;
}
{% endhighlight %}
```

### Styling

Styles are from `_scss/_syntax-highlighting.scss`.

Comment: Not sure why I should highlight my c++ code block using Java. I did try this and it worked, but I ended up switching to [Hexo](https://hexo.io/) before I saw your post.

Comment: I think it should be `cpp`. :D

Answer (score -1):

The plugin I'm currently using for code highlighting is "jekyll-rouge", which supports ''' style markdown well:

https://sacha.me/articles/jekyll-rouge/